# Using store.all adds items to controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using `store.all` to find all the current instances of an model in my store and then setting it as the model for the route in my controller like this:

```
model: function() {
    this.store.all('activeShip');
}
```

That works fine, but I'm having some odd behavoir when I create a new model instance for that type. When I do, it's automatically added to the controllers model even though I never `addObject`.  I've created [a little demo here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hihatusapu/1/edit?html,js,output) to see what I mean. As soon as you create a record, it's included in the model and updated in the view. I figured `store.all` would just run once, gather all the records and be done; not continue to update as new records are created.

Is this the desired behavior, a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: Think these two issues my be related: [#2375](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2375), [#2542](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2542).

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, but maybe not desired in your situation.  It's actually one common criticism of Ember Data--the inability to "fork" a model or RecordArray until the changes are persisted.

Secondly, a call to `this.store.all` returns a `DS.RecordArray`, which actually updates when new records are added to the store.  If you don't want to show new records, consider using something like `return this.store.all('post').filterProperty('isNew', false);` to keep it from showing new records.  Once they're persisted on the server, it will show in the array, but not before.

P.S. You're not actually "setting it as the model" unless you `return this.store.all('activeShip');` (note return).